# IPv6 / IPv4 Third Form conversion?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, conversion

I'm reading about how to [configure IPv6 on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Reading_IPv6_Addresses), I've gotten to the section about Reading IPv6 Addresses and though the first two examples make sense to me, the last one escapes my grasp a bit, as it's been a few years since my last networking class:

How does one convert the third form into the long form?

Here is the example I am having trouble with:

- **third form:**         -  2002::10:0.0.1
- **long form:**         - 2002:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0a00:0001
- **canonicalform:** - 2002::a00:1

I understand hex so far as instead of ending up with the number ten when you count beyond nine you end up with A, B, C, D, E, and F before incrementing the digit in the next column.

Can you please show me how this works using math, not just some online JavaScript converter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IPv4, each byte is represented by a number, 0 through 255; in IPv6, the hex representation is used instead, 00 through ff.  The conversion that's done there is to map the four bytes of the IPv4 address to the last 4 bytes of the IPv6 address:

IPv4:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

IPv6:

```
XXXX::AABB:CCDD
```

So, with an input of `10.0.0.1`, the bytes are `0a`, `00`, `00`, `01`; leading to:

```
::0a00:0001
```

(which shortens to `::a00:1`)

For another example, let's take `192.168.50.254`:

```
::c0a8:32fe
```

Comment: Okay so in ipv6 you have a hexquad, and in ipv4 you have a octet...
a hexquad represents 16 bits...
an octet represents 4 bits?

Comment: Right, except 8 bits per IPv4 octet.  IPv4 has 4 octets of 8 for a total of 32 bits, while IPv6 has 8 colon-separated groups of 16 bits for a total of 128 bits.

Comment: Okay I think I understand this now, here's a rather verbose explanation of the conversion: http://leeand00.tiddlyspot.com/#[[Converting%20IPv4%20addresses%20to%20IPv6%20Equivalent]]

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [conversion to different formats using v6decode](http://v6decode.com/#address=2002::a00:1); try hovering over the different parts of the address to see how they relate between the different formats.